# Is there a first countable and star countable space which is not separable?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

A topological space $X$ is said to be star countable if whenever $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a countable subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $X = \operatorname{St}(K,\mathscr{U})$.

My question is this: Is there a first countable and star countable space which is not separable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 2.20 of [this paper](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/mathjournal/archives/2011/vol12-n2/paper10/v12n2-10pd.pdf) by Petra Staynova is an example, due to R. Winkler, of a first countable, Lindelöf (and hence star-countable), Hausdorff space that is ccc but not separable. Winkler’s paper can be found [here](http://planet-austria.at/buecher/files/1996/ABT2/JID13300.1V1/JID0023.pdf).

$[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with the lexicographic order topology is compact and first countable but not separable.

**Added:** I almost forgot: $\mathsf{CH}$ implies that there is a first countable $L$-space, i.e. a first countable space that is $T_3$, hereditarily Lindelöf, and non-separable, while $\mathsf{MA}+\neg\mathsf{CH}$ implies that no such space exists.